# Android Java There is a way to append into arraylist some objects at a specific index?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Hello I have a `ArrayList<String>` with some strings. I would like to insert a string at a specific index, without loosing the string on that index. I know how to use `list.add(index, string)` but it replaces the string at the index with the new one.

For example I have this ArrayList:

```
index 0 => Orange
index 1 => Melon
index 2 => Apple
index 3 => Strawberry
index 4 => Pear
index 5 => Banana
```

Now I would like to add *Cherry* to index 2, so the result should be:

```
index 0 => Orange
index 1 => Melon
index 2 => Cherry 
index 3 => Apple
index 4 => Strawberry
index 5 => Pear
index 6 => Banana
```

Is there an easy way to do this, because it gives me headache.

Comment: adding at index pushes all elements after `index-1` by 1 position..

Comment: Thank you all, but i was under the impression that that method was doing the opposite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reference: [ArrayList.add(index, element)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29)

```
 void add(int index, E element)
```

> Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list.
>   Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any
>   subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).

Should work on android too...

Comment: Yes i know this method, but deletes the already element from that index. Please read the all content of this question.

Answer (score 3):

`add(int index, E element)` works well:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(
                               "Orange", "Melon", "Apple",
                               "Strawberry", "Pear", "Banana"));
System.out.println(list);
list.add(2, "Cherry");
System.out.println(list);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[Orange, Melon, Apple, Strawberry, Pear, Banana]
[Orange, Melon, Cherry, Apple, Strawberry, Pear, Banana]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to append to existing index, you will need to like this -

```
list.add(index, string + list.remove(index));
```

list.remove(index) will return the Element at the index and also removes it.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but it's probably because the OP wants to add an item at the new index. They don't want to concatenate the new string with the existing item at that index, which is what your code does.

Comment: yes ..the OP's question is not clear. In the first part he has said he needs to append String to the index without losing exsiting String. In the second part it seems he needs to add index by pushing the existing one downwards.

Comment: Very true. I'm assuming from the context that the OP actually means "insert" - I've edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

See : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html

```
void add(int index, E object)
```

Inserts the specified object into this ArrayList at the specified location. The object is   inserted before any previous element at the specified location. If the location is equal to the size of this ArrayList, the object is added at the end.

Parameters:

index: the index at which to insert the object.

object: the object to add.

Throws

IndexOutOfBoundsException   when location < 0 || > size()